# Print comments PDF-XChange viewer

Tags: pdf

I would like to print a pdf document with comments.

I am using [PDF-XChange viewer](http://www.pdf-xchange.de).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Summarize Comments to create a summary of document comments (http://help.tracker-software.com/pdfxe6/index.html?summarize-comments_ed.html). Otherwise, just the highlights are printed.